# django auth : strange error with authenticate()

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using authenticate() to authenticating users manually.
Using admin interface I can see that there is no 'last_login' attribute for Users

Debug traceback is :

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://localhost/login/
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'mobius.polls']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  55.     user.last_login = datetime.datetime.now()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'last_login'
```

I cant figure out, why is there this  discrepancy.
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with `authenticate()`, it seems to be with `login()` which you appear to be passing a `unicode` into, rather than a `django.contrib.auth.models.User` object.

You should probably be getting that User object from `authenticate()`

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
...
login(request, user)
```

[authenticate and login](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in) docs

Comment: Where are you importing `authenticate` from?

Comment: yeah.. found the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The exception value tells it: "user" is a unicode object instead of a django.contrib.auth.models.User object. Are you sure that the database is accessible? try:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> u.last_login
```

This code must work correctly. If not, then there's something wrong with your database setup. (maybe you did not do `python manage.py syncdb` ?)

Please post your database related parts of settings.py as well. From your current information it's not easy to find the cause of your problem.

The **full** traceback is helpful as well.